# Turn Columns into Rows partitioned

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a table like this:

```
CFL52_ID     CFL52_PRICE    CFL51_MILEAGE
------------ --------------- -----------------
1            100000.00       10000
1            200000.00       20000
2            800000.00       10000
2            900000.00       20000
```

I want to pivot the columns into rows. `Mileage` was the column title and `Price` the value. Turning into something like this:

```
CFL52_ID     [10000]         [20000]
------------ --------------- -----------------
1            100000.00       200000.00
2            800000.00       900000.00
```

Notice that id was grouping, prices are pivoted and mileage turning into columns title, Mileage are dynamic -could increment- .

I've tried with no success with this:

```
   SELECT  [10000],[20000]   
    FROM  (     SELECT 
                    CFL52_PRICE as indicatorvalue,          
                    CFL51_MILEAGE as indicatorname        
                FROM [TFL52_PRICES_M] p          
                    INNER JOIN [TFL51_PARAM_MILEAGE] k ON CFL52_CFL51_CODIGO = CFL51_CODIGO       
                WHERE CFL52_DATES = '2018-07-01 00:00:00.000' AND CFL52_DATEEN= '2018-07-02 00:00:00.000') as a   
    pivot 
    (
        max(indicatorvalue) for indicatorname in ([10000],[20000]) 
    ) p
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manage dynamic titles you need dynamic TSQL:

```
if OBJECT_ID('dbo.test') is null 
create table dbo.test(CFL52_ID varchar(50), CFL52_PRICE decimal(18,2), CFL51_MILEAGE int) 
--populate test table
insert into dbo.test values 
(1, 100000.00, 10000), 
(1, 200000.00, 20000), 
(2, 800000.00, 10000), 
(2, 900000.00, 20000)

declare @columns nvarchar(max)='' --holds all the numbers that will become column names 
declare @sql nvarchar(max)='' --contains the TSQL dinamically generated 

--generate dynamic column names
select @columns = @columns + ', [' + cast(CFL51_MILEAGE as varchar(max))+ ']' 
from dbo.test 
group by CFL51_MILEAGE 

--remove first (unnecessary) comma
set @columns = RIGHT(@columns, len(@columns)-2) 

--build dynamic TSQL query
set @sql = @sql + ' select piv.[CFL52_ID], ' + @columns 
set @sql = @sql + ' from ( ' 
set @sql = @sql + ' select [CFL52_ID], [CFL52_PRICE], [CFL51_MILEAGE] ' 
set @sql = @sql + ' from dbo.test ' 
set @sql = @sql + ' ) src ' 
set @sql = @sql + ' pivot ( ' 
set @sql = @sql + ' max([CFL52_PRICE]) ' 
set @sql = @sql + ' for [CFL51_MILEAGE] in ('+@columns+') ' 
set @sql = @sql + ' ) piv ' 

--execute  dynamic TSQL query
exec(@sql)
```

output:

[image]

If you add more rows to your input table with `CFL51_MILEAGE` values of 10000 and 20000, then input and output tables will be:

[image]

If you add more rows to your input table introducing new `CFL51_MILEAGE` values (other than 10000 or 20000), then input and output tables will be:

[image]

Comment: Awesome Andrea, this is what I needed. I going to save this for further implementations. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

just use conditional aggregation instead. You also should use aliases to indicate which table a column belongs to.

```
select CFL52_ID
    , [10000] = MAX(case when CFL51_MILEAGE = 10000 then CFL52_PRICE end)
    , [20000] = MAX(case when CFL51_MILEAGE = 20000 then CFL52_PRICE end)
FROM [TFL52_PRICES_M] p          
INNER JOIN [TFL51_PARAM_MILEAGE] k ON CFL52_CFL51_CODIGO = CFL51_CODIGO       
WHERE CFL52_DATES = '2018-07-01 00:00:00.000' 
    AND CFL52_DATEEN= '2018-07-02 00:00:00.000'
group by CFL52_ID
```

Comment: Titles are Dynamic. Changes

Comment: I am sure that means something to you but it isn't clear to me. Do you mean you don't the value of CFL51_MILEAGE? That means you need a dynamic cross tab here. Or if you stick with pivot you need a dynamic pivot. Perhaps you need to revisit the question and clarify this a bit.